# Open a (resulting from http get) PDF in client's browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, fetch-api

In order to get a report to the user from my API data, I use a renderer, that takes my data and returns a PDF. I try to open that resulting PDF in browser:

```
<a class="btn" onclick="fetchDataAndGetReport()">Get sales report</a>
```

and here is the js code that gets the report:

```
async function fetchDataAndGetReport() {
    const resp = await fetch("/api/sales")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(renderReportAndGetRenderId);
}

async function renderReportAndGetRenderId(data) {
    const templateId = 'myId';
    const resp = await fetch(`https://my-renderer.io/render/${templateId}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'mykey',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'                
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            convertTo: 'pdf',
            data: data
        })
    }).then(res => res.json());
    if (resp && resp.success === true && resp.data && resp.data.renderId) {
    
        // HERE, I get the resulting PDF via HTTP GET, how to open it in browser ??
        return (`https://my-renderer.io/render/${resp.data.renderId}`);
        
    } else if (resp && resp.error) {
        return (resp.error);
    }
}
```

It returns me the PDF path, something like `https://my-renderer.io/render/my-renderId.pdf`.

However when I click on the button, I see the return is OK, but don't see any PDF opening.
Probably I missed an elementary step.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a way like this:

```
window.open(resp);
```

in the first function:

```
async function fetchDataAndGetReport() {
    const resp = await fetch("/api/sales")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(renderReportAndGetRenderId);
    window.open(resp);
}
```